# What are the adverb and adjective for "content"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Well, as it is said in the title of my question, I'm wondering what the adjective and adverb of *content* are. Similarly, we have *context* whose adjective and adverb are *contextual* and *contextually* respectively, but what about *content*?

Comment: Did you mean *content* as regards that which is contained in something? Or did you mean *content* meaning *in a state of peaceful happiness* - which is of course already an adjective? If you are talking about the latter, the adverb would be *contentedly*. But if we are discussing *the contents of a box*, I am afraid that it doesn't have inflections. You will need to use things like *content specific, content regarding, content determined, content depending etc*.

Comment: @WS2 I meant content like "content of a page, book etc".

Comment: You could use prepositions to provide descriptive use, such as *the book was lacking in content*, or *his ideas are full of content*.

Comment: Note that the verb most closely corresponding to the noun "content" (meaning "what's inside") is "contain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not asking about the verb *content*. If you are, then they would be *contented* and *contentedly*.

I am quite sure you are asking about the noun *content*, like the nutritional content of milk, the news content of newspaper, the story content of a book, etc.

The adjective would be *content-related*. For example,

- He asked me **contextual** questions about the book.
- He asked me **content-related** questions about the book.

The adverb would *content-wise*. For example,

- He spoke **contextually** about Paul's admonishment that women kept quiet, but asked their husbands at home.
- He spoke **content-wise** about his recent book on Paul's admonishments for women.

Comment: "Content-wise" is an adverb?  Can you explain this a bit more.  Usually an adverb can move around, but yours cannot go in front of spoke: "He content-wise spoke about..."

Comment: He likewise spoke to me. He spoke to me likewise.

Comment: So in this sentence, "Content-wise, this is a good book to read." "content-wise" is an adverb?  Maybe this is a class of adverbs I am not familiar with.  I honestly don't know, but it seems fishy to me, that the adverb cannot go in front of the verb in your example.  Maybe this would be good for a "Question" on this site.

Comment: well, I am more confused now oO

Comment: feev, I did not expect you to have problems understanding the function of an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's will be the following adjective in use

> to be contained in

Content means there will be something in it. Something is being contained by something.

Comment: Content and contain are totally two different things. One is noun while the other is a verb.

Comment: If you so want: Context and contextual are also two totally different things. One is a noun while the other is an adjective.

Comment: But their origin is a same word. For God sake!

Comment: content (n.) = "that which is contained," early 15c., from Latin contentum, contenta, noun use of past participle of continere.

Comment: contain (v.) late 13c., from Old French contein-, stem of contenir, from Latin continere.